# Why doesn't the following code need a python interpreter?

Tags: python, numpy, numba, gil

I was watching a [video](https://youtu.be/x58W9A2lnQc?t=1018) to learn Numba. At 17:00 the presenter has the following code on screen:

```
@njit
def simulate_spring_mass_funky_damper(x0, T=10, dt=0.0001, vt=1.0):
    times = np.arange(0, T, dt)
    positions = np.zeros_like(times)
    
    v = 0
    a = 0
    x = x0
    positions[0] = x0/x0
    
    for ii in range(len(times)):
        if ii == 0:
            continue
        t = times[ii]
        a = friction_fn(v, vt) - 100*x
        v = v + a*dt
        x = x + v*dt
        positions[ii] = x/x0
    return times, positions
```

The presenter then proceeds to instruct numba to release the GIL using `jnit(nogil=True)`. His argument is

> This function does not need to access the python interpreter while it is running. In fact, we made sure of that. So we can additionally tell it to release the GIL

The presenter then uses this code with multi threads:

```
%%time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

with ThreadPoolExecutor(8) as ex:
    ex.map(simulate_spring_mass_funky_damper, np.arange(0, 1000, 0.1))
```

I understand that GIL is required by the thread that wishes to interact with the python interpreter. And if a code does not need to interact with python interpreter then isn't it that releasing or not releasing GIL is moot?

1. I do not understand how this function does not need python interpreter?
2. If the code does not need to interact with the GIL then what is even the point of releasing the GIL? It won't interact with python interpreter anyway and GIL won't come into play

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I do not understand how this function does not need python interpreter?

Numba use a JIT compiler (LLVM-Lite) to translate a Python code to a fast binary that can run in the context of the interpreter. When a function use the `@njit` decorator (or the equivalent `@jit(nopython=True)`), Numba generates internally two functions: one is a *wrapper* that will *convert input pure-Python objects* to internal native types, and another will perform the actual computation (output values are converted back by the wrapping function then). The thing is *objects like CPython lists or dictionaries needs to be protected by the GIL with CPython but internal Numba native values do not*. Numba converts CPython integer objects to low-level fixed-size integers, lists/dictionaries and Numpy arrays are typed and are translated to internal data-structures that are independent of CPython. However, this method *does not work for all CPython objects*: Numba cannot work on CPython objects while releasing the GIL.

The case of Numpy arrays is a bit special since Numpy is designed so the GIL can be released when you work with *native array* (only with them). Numpy arrays containing CPython objects need the GIL. Note also that Numba do not directly use the Numpy CPython API. It re-implements Numpy internally.

For lists and dictionaries, Numba copy the whole data-structure in another one that do not need the GIL. This is only possible with *fully-typed* list/dictionaries though. The wrapping function will when convert back the typed lists/dictionaries to CPython ones. This operation is expensive.

**Put it shortly:** in your case, the wrapping function generated by Numba *need the GIL* because it works with *CPython objects* but the actual computing function do need need the GIL. Thus, specifying `nogil=True` cause the wrapping function to release the GIL before it calls the computing function (and then acquire the GIL back after the computing function has been executed).

> If the code does not need to interact with the GIL then what is even the point of releasing the GIL? It won't interact with python interpreter anyway and GIL won't come into play

Well, if you use the `@njit` decorator (or the equivalent `@jit(nopython=True)`), then specifying `nogil=True` is often useless if the code is called sequentially since the GIL cannot be used anyway (since Numba "generates code that does not access the Python C API" in this case according to the documentation).

However, in your case, there are many threads calling the Numba function. If the GIL is not released by the generated wrapping function, then the Numba computing function is executed serially (less efficiently than a sequential code due to expensive contexts switches between threads). Releasing the GIL solve this problem. Note that the wrapping code is still executed serially because of the GIL (which is required because of the CPython object convertion).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually ```nogil=True``` made the code faster with multithreading. You can check the video post 16:26. The presenter runs it with and without GIL released on 8 cores and the runtime drops by a factor of 6

Comment: Also, here is the gist for trying that code out yourself: https://gist.github.com/safijari/fa4eba922cea19b3bc6a693fe2a97af7

Comment: Well, you are right. I missed the case where a Numba function is called from multiple thread (which is your case). I used to not call Numba functions from a multithreaded context because Numba provides a (much) simpler way to parallelize codes (using `prange` and `parallel=True`, which is also often faster than using CPython thread). This case is quite rare. Using the Numba thread should be preferred although it may not always be always possible. I updated the answer to explain precisely this case (the part after "Put it shortly").