# Threading vs Numba performance

Tags: python, multithreading, numba

I wanted to ask if there was a particular benefit to use the threading library over the auto parallel flags in numba? And has anyone tested any benchmarks between both?

Comment: In CPython, threading is only going to be effective for IO bound tasks.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga AFAIK this is only the case if the GIL is not disabled (default case). The same thing apply for Numba thread except that Numba is mainly useful with the `nopython`/`njit` flag which [disable the GIL in the computing part of the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70433667) (and Numba parallel loops cannot work on Python object anyway so the GIL is not a problem).

Comment: @JON Do you ask the difference between the basic Python threading package VS Numba `prange`+`parallel`, or the difference between the multiple threading layers in Numba? If this is the first, then the above linked answer should mainly answer the question.